# How to print a vertical histogram in C++

Tags: c++, loops, ascii-art

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int a, b, c, i;
    cin >> a >> b >>  c;
    
    for ( i = 0;  i < a; i++)
        cout << "*" << endl;
        
    for ( i = 0; i < b; i++)
        cout << "*" << endl;
    
    for ( i = 0; i < c; i++)
        cout << "*" << endl;
}
```

I'm aware that output is as same as:

```
for ( i = 0; i < a + b + c; i++ ){
cout << "*" << endl;
}
```

So for 2 3 1 i get:

> - 
> - 
> - 
> - 
> - 
> - 

What i want is:

```
     *

*    * 

*    *    *   //Horizontal distance between 2 shapes don't matter.
```

I've no idea about how to put cursor in the right place considering the printing must be done from up to down.

I hope following example helps and also, if possible, printing of each column must be done by using a separate function.

First loop:

```
*

*
```

Second loop:

```
    *

*   *

*   *
```

Last loop:

```
    *

*   *

*   *   *
```

Printing must be done in exactly that order. Print first column, then second and goes on like this.

Comment: [**`std::setw`**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setw)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to rethink your printing a little. To start with you need to find out the highest column, as this is the number of lines you will have.

I would do something like this:

```
int high = std::max(std::max(a, b), c);

for (int i = high; i > 0; i--)
{
    if (i <= a)
        std::cout << " * ";
    else
        std::cout << "   ";

    if (i <= b)
        std::cout << " * ";
    else
        std::cout << "   ";

    if (i <= c)
        std::cout << " * ";
    else
        std::cout << "   ";

    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

If you want arbitrary number of columns, you might want to put them in a `std::vector`, and have a inner loop for that.

---

For an arbitrary amount of columns, you could use something like:

```
// Get the input
std::cout << "Please enter numbers, all on one line, and end with ENTER: ";
std::string input;
std::getline(std::cin, input);

// Parse the input into integers
std::istringstream istr(input);
std::vector<int> values(std::istream_iterator<int>(istr),
                        std::istream_iterator<int>());

// Get the max value
int max_value = *std::max_element(values.begin(), values.end());

// Print the columns
for (int current = max_value; current > 0; current--)
{
    for (const int& value : values)
    {
        if (current <= value)
            std::cout << " * ";
        else
            std::cout << "   ";
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Is there a way of doing this without determining the biggest number ?

Comment: @user2362377 No not really, as it will be the number of lines you need to print. Fortunately it's easy to find that out in a loop if you use e.g. a `std::vector` to keep the values.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer but i'm afraid i wasn't clear when wasking the question.I updated it i'd be glad if you can find time to check it.

Comment: @user2362377 You can't do it using only standard C++ functionality. You need to use either external libraries (like [curses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curses_%28programming_library%29)) or use special character codes (like [VT100 cursor control codes](http://www.termsys.demon.co.uk/vtansi.htm#cursor)) to control where to do the printing.

Comment: So there's no command to bring cursor at top in standard C++?

Comment: @user2362377 No there isn't.

Answer (score 0):

Converting [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16493000/6243352) into a runnable program, with some adjustments to ensure it compiles on C++ 17:

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::cout << "Please enter numbers, all on one line, and end with ENTER: ";
    std::string input;
    std::getline(std::cin, input);
    std::istringstream istr(input);
    const std::vector<int> values{std::istream_iterator<int>(istr),
                                  std::istream_iterator<int>()};
    int max_value = *std::max_element(values.begin(), values.end());

    for (int i = max_value; i > 0; i--) {
        for (const int &value : values) {
            std::cout << (i > value ? "   " : " * ");
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
}
```

You could put this into one function, but there's no point in writing different functions to print each column.

Answer (score -2):

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int f[3];
int main()
{
    int a, b, c, i;
    cin >> f[0] >> f[1] >>  f[2];

    int m = max(max(f[0],f[1]),f[2]);
    for(int i=m;i>=1;i--)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<3;j++)
            if (f[j]<i) cout <<' ';
            else cout <<'*';
        cout<<endl;
    }
}
```

Testing:

```
Input: 2 3 1
Output:
 *
**
***
```

Comment: Ugh, really `using namespace std`?

Comment: Posting the word "Code" and a block of the same with no explanation of why it's a solution isn't an answer.