# How to create an ASCII-Art bar chart in C++?

Tags: c++, while-loop

I have a question regarding C++ while loop. I want to draw an ASCII-Art bar chart such as this:

```
      *
*     *
* *   *
* * * *
* * * *
* * * *
```

For this I need to fill the output from below. I have the following code which draws a single bar from "top to bottom", but I need to somehow leave the space above the bar so that the other bars fit nicely:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a,n;
    cout << "Enter a value in range 5-20 \n";
    cin >> a;
    while (n<a) {
        cout<<"* \n";
        n=n+1;
    }
 }
```

As mentioned, this code doesn’t leave space above the bar, so it won’t align with other bars. How can I solve this?

Comment: even if you print the last star first, it will appear in the first line...

Comment: Can you please give an example with numbers, so the order is more clear? I don't really understand what you are asking at the moment.

Comment: Do you mean you want your program to output in console *higher* than previous output? If so, it's impossible via `cout` (which - long story short - creates strictly left-to-right, top-to-bottom text stream).

Comment: actually i m writing code for four different inputs such that their outputs should vary

Comment: note that your question is about output, not while loops, because not matter in what order you perform `cout << "* \n";` it will print a star and go to the next line

Comment: i am trying to write code for this
[link]www.jawadadil.tk/uploads/Screenshot_2.png

Comment: tobi303 see this picture

Comment: you just need to place some empty lines before the stars...

Comment: no that will not be the solution

Comment: @JawadAdil Write it line by line, leaving spaces if you don't need stars in a particular column on this particular line. (There exist OS-dependent options like `initgraph()`, but I wouldn't recommend resorting to them.)

Comment: why not? anyhow you have to print multiple columns while you print only one. In that case not full blank lines, but empty entries, before printing the start

Comment: imho you are on the wrong track. You dont need to print them from bottom up, you just have to print them that they are aligned bottom up. No need to reverse the while loop or the order in which you print them

Comment: I took the liberty to edit the actual question you posed in the comments into your question to prevent your question from becoming closed. The answers already base on that. If you feel I am mis-representing your actual question, roll the edit back and/or let me know.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to print a vertical histogram in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16492957/how-to-print-a-vertical-histogram-in-c)

Answer (score 1):

Standard C++ doesn't provide any way to do that.

Given the requirement you've shown in the comments (you want to create a bar graph out of characters), what you probably want to do is start by creating a 2D array of characters the size of the output you're going to create.

- Start by filling it with space characters.
- Then fill in asterisks where needed to create your chart. Since it's just an array, you can access elements in any order you prefer.
- Then write it out to the screen from left to right, top to bottom.

Answer (score 0):

I can say try to find how many no of rows in your full screen mode you have
Follow these steps:

1. Print the screen from top to bottom with stars.
2. Then count those stars to get idea how many lines(row) on your screen are.

ex.

```
*
*
*
*
```

This means you have 4 rows.

3. Then take input from user.
4. Now subtract user input from no of rows. i.e. 4
   so if user give you 2 as input then fill screen with two spaces then 2 stars.